# How to implement re.search() in my code?

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I am working on a binary classification problem with text data. I want to classify the words of the text based on their appearances in some well-defined Word class features I have chosen.
For now, I have been searching the occurrence of the entire word of text in each word class and incrementing the count of that word class on match. This count is further being used to calculate frequency of each word class. Here is my code:

```
import nltk
import re

def wordClassFeatures(text):
    home = """woke home sleep today eat tired wake watch
        watched dinner ate bed day house tv early boring
        yesterday watching sit"""

    conversation = """know people think person tell feel friends
talk new talking mean ask understand feelings care thinking
friend relationship realize question answer saying"""


    countHome = countConversation =0

    totalWords = len(text.split())

    text = text.lower()
    text = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    conversation = nltk.word_tokenize(conversation)
    home = nltk.word_tokenize(home)
'''
    for word in text:
        if word in conversation: #this is my current approach
            countConversation += 1
        if word in home:
            countHome += 1
'''

    for word in text:
        if re.search(word, conversation): #this is what I want to implement
            countConversation += 1
        if re.search(word, home):
            countHome += 1

    countConversation /= 1.0*totalWords
    countHome /= 1.0*totalWords

    return(countHome,countConversation)

text = """ Long time no see. Like always I was rewriting it from scratch a couple of times. But nevertheless 
it's still java and now it uses metropolis sampling to help that poor path tracing converge. Btw. I did MLT on 
yesterday evening after 2 beers (it had to be Ballmer peak). Altough the implementation is still very fresh it 
easily outperforms standard path tracing, what is to be seen especially when difficult caustics are involved. 
I've implemented spectral rendering too, it was very easy actually, cause all computations on wavelengths are 
linear just like rgb. But then I realised that even if it does feel more physically correct to do so, whats the 
point? 3d applications are operating in rgb color space, and because I cant represent a rgb color as spectrum 
interchangeably I have to approximate it, so as long as I'm not running a physical simulation or something I don't
see the benefits (please correct me if I'm wrong), thus I abandoned that."""

print(wordClassFeatures(text))
```

The demerit of this is that I now have an extra overhead of stemming each word of all the word classes since the words in the text must match explicitly to fall into a word class. Therefore, I am now trying to input each word of the text as a regular expression and search for it in each word class.
This throws the error:

```
line 362, in wordClassFeatures
if re.search(conversation, word):
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 289, in _compile
    p, loc = _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I know there's a major mistake in the syntax but I couldn't find it on the net as most of the syntax for re.search are in the format:

> re.search("thank|appreciate|advance", x)

Is there any way to properly implement this?

Comment: It should be `re.search(word, conversation)`.

Comment: @Rawing Tried it. Throws this error: line 362, in wordClassFeatures
    if re.search(word, conversation):
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: This question needs a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: If you're going to use regular expressions, use them. If you are going to use a different approach (like nltk) then use it. You can't just mix and match all willy-nilly. Regexes are a red-herring here: you need to just ask how to use the library, preferably with examples of what you've already tried from the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `re.search` is looking for a `string` or `buffer` and not `list` that the code is feeding for *conversation* and *home* variables.

Also, when you are `tokenizing` you are doing so with all the special characters for *text* which is trowing search off.

So, first we need to  strip *text* of special characters

```
text = re.sub('\W+',' ', text ) #strip text of all special characters
```

Next, we leave *conversation* and *home* variables as it is (in string format) and not `tokenize`

```
#conversation = nltk.word_tokenize(conversation)
#home = nltk.word_tokenize(home)
```

We get desired answer:

```
(0.21301775147928995, 0.20118343195266272)
```

Full code below:

```
import nltk
import re

def wordClassFeatures(text):
    home = """woke home sleep today eat tired wake watch
        watched dinner ate bed day house tv early boring
        yesterday watching sit"""

    conversation = """know people think person tell feel friends
talk new talking mean ask understand feelings care thinking
friend relationship realize question answer saying"""

    text = re.sub('\W+',' ', text ) #strip text of all special characters

    countHome = countConversation =0

    totalWords = len(text.split())

    text = text.lower()
    text = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    #conversation = nltk.word_tokenize(conversation)
    #home = nltk.word_tokenize(home)
    '''
        for word in text:
            if word in conversation: #this is my current approach
                countConversation += 1
            if word in home:
                countHome += 1
    '''

    for word in text:
        if re.search(word, conversation): #this is what I want to implement
            countConversation += 1
        if re.search(word, home):
            countHome += 1

    countConversation /= 1.0*totalWords
    countHome /= 1.0*totalWords

    return(countHome,countConversation)

text = """ Long time no see. Like always I was rewriting it from scratch a couple of times. But nevertheless 
it's still java and now it uses metropolis sampling to help that poor path tracing converge. Btw. I did MLT on 
yesterday evening after 2 beers (it had to be Ballmer peak). Altough the implementation is still very fresh it 
easily outperforms standard path tracing, what is to be seen especially when difficult caustics are involved. 
I've implemented spectral rendering too, it was very easy actually, cause all computations on wavelengths are 
linear just like rgb. But then I realised that even if it does feel more physically correct to do so, whats the 
point? 3d applications are operating in rgb color space, and because I cant represent a rgb color as spectrum 
interchangeably I have to approximate it, so as long as I'm not running a physical simulation or something I don't
see the benefits (please correct me if I'm wrong), thus I abandoned that."""

print(wordClassFeatures(text))
```